# Trim a line on a text file from a website after making a list

Tags: c#

**Overview**

Hey, what I am trying to do is create an add-on for a game where when they join it will check on my website a list of names I have in a text file.

**Code**

```
public override void Init()
{

    Player.Joined += (object sender, PlayerEventArgs e) =>
    {
        string autokick = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://leeizazombie.cba.pl/server/autokick.txt");
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(autokick);
        List<string> autokicklist = new List<string>();
        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            autokicklist.Add(line);
        }
        if (autokicklist.Contains(e.Player.name))
        {
            e.Player.Kick("Auto-Kick: "); //Reason goes in this part after kicking the player.
        }
    };
}
```

**Problem**

I can't figure out how to get the reason part of the text and exclude the reason part when searching each line, This is an example of a line:

> LeeIzaZombie+ : Kicked for a test run.

Where LeeIzaZombie+ is the username and "Kicked for a test run." is the reason.

Comment: Is the delimiter the `:` character, then? For example, if the string you return is `LeelzaZombie+ : Kicked for test run`, you `string.Split()` it on the `:` character (and `Trim()` it to clean up the leading/trailing whitespace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *message* always contains a  `':'` after *username* you can `Split` it and get the reason like this:

```
e.Player.Kick("Auto-Kick: {0}", line.Split(':')[1].Trim());
```

This should work as expected if the reason doesn't contain any `:`. If it does you can try:

```
var reason = string.Join(":", line.Split(':').Skip(1));
e.Player.Kick("Auto-Kick: {0}", reason);
```

Update: in order to access `line` from  `if` statement you should declare it outside of the loop:

```
string line = "";
while (sr.Peek() != -1)
{
     line = sr.ReadLine();
     autokicklist.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: It won't always contain a plus because it's a certain format the usernames get

Comment: An error shows that "The name "line" does not exist in the current context".

Comment: See my edit.Your line variable should be declared outside of the loop

Comment: Wait, it says System.Array does not contain "Skip"

Comment: @user3006430 include the System.Linq namespace with: `using System.Linq;`